# how to avoid date conversion in concatenation in r

Tags: r, date

I concatenated Sys.Date() with another string argument,

```
c("a string", Sys.Date())
```

when I get individual elements back, the date got converted to a string with its numeric value. Is there a way to keep it to the standard format of "yyyy-mm-dd", or how do I convert it from the numeric value back to this format? using as.Date() failed.

Comment: you need to convert the date to character before. `c("a string", as.character(Sys.Date()))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you could put the date as string from the beginning:

```
c("a string", as.character(Sys.Date()))
```

and use lubridate library to convert back to date

```
library(lubridate)
ymd(as.character(Sys.Date()))
```

To convert numeric to date use

```
myVector<-c("a string", Sys.Date())
as.Date(as.numeric(myVector[2]),origin="1970-01-01")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have mixed types in a vector (`c`). Use `list` for such cases.

Answer (score 1):

Convert date to character. You can choose format of your choice.

```
a <- c("a string",format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%m-%d"))
> a
[1] "a string"   "2018-01-13"
```

OR

```
> a <- c("a string",format(Sys.Date(), "%Y-%B-%d"))
> a
[1] "a string"        "2018-January-13"
```